# Else Statement doesn't work in unity?

Tags: if-statement, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Alright so here is my code. This should be really simple but it doesn't want to work with me for some reason. Raycast sends a ray from the mouse, if it hits an object with a tag, it assigns a number to a variable. If it doesn't hit an object, then it sets the variable as -99. For some reason mine is hanging on:

A. I don't hit the objects, it outputs -99 the first time but after that it hangs on getting assigned 4.

B.I hit the objects and it will work just fine. After I click OFF the objects it hangs on the variable from the object I just hit previously.

```
em.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameFunctions : MonoBehaviour {

int Hitnum = -99;
void Start () {
    }

    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            objectCheck ();
        }

    }
    //end of UPDATE function



public void objectCheck () {
        RaycastHit hit; 
        Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 10000.0f)) {
            if (hit.collider.tag == "Box") {
                Hitnum = 1;
            } else if (hit.collider.tag == "Sphere") {
                Hitnum = 2;
            } else if (hit.collider.tag == "Pyramid") {
                Hitnum = 3;
            } else if (hit.collider.tag == "Trapezoid") {
                Hitnum = 4;
            } else {
                Hitnum = -99;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log (Hitnum);
    }
    //end of check

}
```

Thanks in advance. This is driving me nuts because it should be simple.

EDIT: posted full code this time, yes all of it. I should mention that there are no other objects with tags, it's just null space. This was supposed to be a very basic shape identifier for kids.

EDIT:EDIT: I expect it to put out -99 if you do not hit the object. Later I will probably do something with the numbers but right now I jest need to fix this.

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: You should edit your question to state what you expect to happen then state what is currently happening. You did not do that and this will be hard to actually answer. With the current question, no one can tell what you expect. Also, please tell us what function that run is being called from.

Comment: 1. Could you place a further else for the first if (Physics...) and give Hitnum a certain value there to check wether it is stuck on it or not. 2. To know if a variable gets overwritten or just simply stays at its old value you could increase the variable instead of overwriting it, sou you may know where it gets stuck 3. Since else if is not so well readable, how about changing it to a switch case statement?

Comment: You could actually simplify your method with a Dictionary<string, int>.

Answer (score 1):

Restarted unity, everything works fine now. Thanks. Looked through my settings to see what had changed. I earlier deleted the background that had a background tag on it. I guess unity decided that if there is not hit on raycast, it will get the object that it last hit?

Comment: What happens is that if a Raycast doesn't hit anything it wont enter the first if statement  if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 10000.0f)) it will return false and Hitnum will keep the old value. So you would also need an else statement after first if statement

Comment: try doing a switch(myString){case "Sphere":... case "Pyramid":.. case null: ...}, better than elseif structures and more code friendly